# saving console messages to file in iphone

Tags: iphone, console

Is there any way to save all the console messages to a file in iphone ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They go to the system log. You can see it from the organizer in Xcode.

If you really need the file, you can redirect stderr:

```
 NSString* myLogfile = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"log.txt"];
 int fd = open([myLogfile fileSystemRepresentation], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0664);
 dup2(fd, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste to a text editor also works, and lets you select just the parts of your current interest.